# Xna game launcher not working

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, xna-4.0, launcher

I made a launcher for my game and successfully found the code to launch the game. But for some reason it doesn't work. The error message is `InvalidOperationException`

Is there an easier way to do this? Or how can I fix this?

This is the code:

```
private void Startgame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (Zombie_Shooter.GameCode game = new Zombie_Shooter.GameCode())
   {
       game.Run();
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `GameCode` and `Run()`?

Comment: GameCode is the name of the class in Zombie_Shooter and Run() is apparently the instruction to run the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you can try this ?

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{    
     Game1 game = new Game();    
     game.Run();
});


private void Startgame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   thread.Start();
   thread.Join();
}
```